# IIS7 Rewirte mapping to ignore querystring

Tags: iis-7

Am trying to setup rewrite on server but IIS configuration is not my strong point. This probably easy for someone who know how.

Basically have removed an old page from the site but there are still a number of links in the public domain to this page. What I want is to redirect any entry to the page regardless of what the querystring contains to just one page.

e.g. oldpage.aspx?id=12345 to newpage.aspx

I'm sure this should be a simple thing but can't figure it out.